# Issue while running the service builder on life ray

Tags: spring, hibernate, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

With reference to the following tutorial, https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/generating-your-service-layer-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en I have created and deployed the service builder. Now view page is showing as expected and on click of Add location button the new form is showing up with respective fields, There I am entering some data and trying to save the data. While saving (On click of save button) I am getting errors, The logs are as follows,

```
15:45:10,445 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-14][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] invalid ORDER BY expression
15:45:10,529 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-14][BasePersistenceImpl:244] Caught unexpected exception org.hib
ernate.exception.SQLGrammarException
15:45:10,530 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-14][EventLocalServiceImpl:168] null
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: co
uld not execute query
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePers
istenceImpl.java:251)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.findWithDynamicQuery(Base
PersistenceImpl.java:144)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.countWithDynamicQuery(Bas
ePersistenceImpl.java:105)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.countWithDynamicQuery(Bas
ePersistenceImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320
)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMe
thodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvo
cation.java:150)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice.invoke(ShardPersistenceAdvice.
java:54)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvo
cation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationIn
terceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvo
cation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy471.countWithDynamicQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.rivetlogic.event.service.impl.EventLocalServiceImpl.getUpcomingEventsCount(EventLocal
ServiceImpl.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvoca
tion.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransacti
onExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionIntercepto
r.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvoca
tion.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at $Proxy470.getUpcomingEventsCount(Unknown Source)
        at com.rivetlogic.event.service.EventLocalServiceUtil.getUpcomingEventsCount(EventLocalServi
ceUtil.java:349)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.eventManagementPortlet.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:420)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.ja
va:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.ja
va:331)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.jav
a:112)
        at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:371)
        at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:387)
        at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doView(MVCPortlet.java:144)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:213)
        at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:323)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
        at com.rivetlogic.event.portlet.EventsManagementPortlet.render(EventsManagementPortlet.java:
220)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
        at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilt
erChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.ja
va:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:656)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:362)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java
:1233)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:5
7)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequ
estDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequest
DispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrappe
r.java:141)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrappe
r.java:126)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:1
56)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:
125)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java
:107)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCal
l(PortletRenderer.java:180)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCal
l(PortletRenderer.java:1)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.j
ava:69)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExe
cutor.java:682)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:593)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryImpl.list(DynamicQueryImpl.java:94)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryImpl.list(DynamicQueryImpl.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.findWithDynamicQuery(Base
PersistenceImpl.java:141)
        ... 91 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid ORDER BY expression
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Util.java:232)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3893)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCConnection.java:643)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:162)

        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocatio
nHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at $Proxy4.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
        ... 99 more
```

Did I miss any configurations? Do I need to add any datasource in any config file? Any suggestions why am I getting the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid ORDER BY expression
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Util.java:232)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3893)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCConnection.java:643)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:162)
```

From above exception its looks like **invalid ORDER BY** expression so something going wrong in your query. 
Can you please provide the **sample query** or **service.xml** code you are using for the same?

Comment: the service.xml might suffice, unless it's specifically from Java code that adds the ORDER BY clause in a custom SQL query.